# Hipotético programa para maquina registradora

Tags: c

Estoy creando un programa en C para una hipotética caja registradora, la cual devuelve el cambio con el menor número de monedas posible. Esas monedas son de 2 euros, 1 euro y 50, 20, 10, 5, 2 y 1 céntimo. Mi pregunta es si alguien me podría ayudar a encontrar el error, ya que al ejecutarlo se aproxima y no da el resultado exacto y, por ello, las monedas equivocadas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "intro.h"

int main (void) {

    string dependiente = "HGI";
    float precio, pago;

    // Imprime el nombre del dependiente previamente señalado.
    printf ("Dependiente: %s\n", dependiente);

    // Pide al usuario el precio del artículo y lo que paga el cliente.
    printf ("Introduzca el precio del artículo en euros.\n");
    precio = get_user_int();

    printf ("Introduzca la cantidad pagada por el artículo en euros.\n");
    pago = get_user_int();

    // Calcula los euros de cambio.
    float cambio = pago - precio;
    float cambiocent = 100 * cambio;
    printf ("Cambio a devolver: %.2f€ (%f céntimos)\n", cambio, cambiocent);

    // Calcula las monedas que se necesitan para devolver el cambio.

    const float moneda_dos_euros = 200;
    const float moneda_un_euro = 100;
    const float moneda_cincuenta_cent = 50;
    const float moneda_veinte_cent = 20;
    const float moneda_diez_cent = 10;
    const float moneda_cinco_cent = 5;
    const float moneda_dos_cent = 2;
    const float moneda_un_cent = 1;


    float num_monedas_2e = cambio / moneda_dos_euros;
    float num_monedas_1e = cambio - (num_monedas_2e * 2) / moneda_un_euro;
    float num_monedas_50c = cambio - (num_monedas_1e / moneda_cincuenta_cent);
    float num_monedas_20c = cambio - (num_monedas_50c / moneda_veinte_cent);
    float num_monedas_10c = cambio - (num_monedas_20c / moneda_diez_cent);
    float num_monedas_5c = cambio - (num_monedas_10c / moneda_cinco_cent);
    float num_monedas_2c = cambio - (num_monedas_5c / moneda_dos_cent);
    float num_monedas_1c = cambio - (num_monedas_2c / moneda_un_cent);


    float total_monedas = num_monedas_2e + num_monedas_1e + num_monedas_50c + num_monedas_20c + num_monedas_10c + num_monedas_5c + num_monedas_2c + num_monedas_1c;

    printf ("Monedas utilizadas para el cambio: %.0f\n", total_monedas);
    printf ("Monedas de 2€ utilizadas: %.0f\n", num_monedas_2e);
    printf ("Monedas de 1€ utilizadas: %.0f\n", num_monedas_1e);
    printf ("Monedas de 50 céntimos utilizadas: %.0f\n", num_monedas_50c);
    printf ("Monedas de 20 céntimos utilizadas: %.0f\n", num_monedas_20c);
    printf ("Monedas de 10 céntimos utilizadas: %.0f\n", num_monedas_10c);
    printf ("Monedas de 5 céntimos utilizadas: %.0f\n", num_monedas_5c);
    printf ("Monedas de 2 céntimos utilizadas: %.0f\n", num_monedas_2c);
    printf ("Monedas de 1 céntimo utilizadas: %.0f\n", num_monedas_1c);



return 0;
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

En la escuela hice un programa similar en Java, nunca he programado en C asi que no se si tambien puedas utilizar el operador % para que te de el reciduo de la division si es asi podrias intentar primero hacer una division con ( / ) para que sepas cuantas monedas de X denominacion vas a dar y despues guardar el reciduo en uana variable (cambioPendiente) por ejemplo haciendo la operacion de (cambio % monedaDeXDenominacion).

espero te sea de ayuda, saludos!